# Getting ObjectCollectedException occurred while retrieving value from JSON object

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am getting

> ```
> com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException occurred while retrieving value
> ```

while reading the .json file and put the value into the `HashMap`. I got the value in my json object for few second then I can see error message as "Unknown Value" (`com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException occurred while retrieving value`)

Below is the code which I have written. I have attached screen shot of the error message

```
Map < String, JSONObject > i18nLables = new HashMap < String, JSONObject > ();
//Read the properties file  for file location 
Properties properties = myUtil.getProperties("label.properties");
String path = properties.getProperty("label.file.location");
File directoryToRead = new File(path);

if (directoryToRead.isDirectory() && directoryToRead.listFiles().length > 0) {

    File[] allFilesInDirectory = directoryToRead.listFiles();
    for (File file: allFilesInDirectory) {

        try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file.toString())) {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsobj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(
                new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

            String fileName = file.getName();

            //key - en or fr..etc
            //value - JSON object
            i18nLables.put(fileName.split("_")[1].substring(0, 2), jsobj);
        } catch (ObjectStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
return i18nLables;
```

**Below is the error message while debug above code**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should update your Eclipse to a later version. According to these notes it has been resolved in version 4.18 (Eclipse 2020-12):

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.18/jdt.php#logicalstructure-gc